# WPF Button IsEnabled Check on Multiple Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the IsEnabled property of a XAML button configured with the following databinding currently:

```
<Button Name="ThirdPartyPostoneButton" Content="Postpone"
        Click ="postponeThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" Margin="5,5,0,0"
        Height="25" IsEnabled="{Binding Item3.CanDefer}"/>
```

I need to also add a check for `IsEnabled="{Binding Item3.InstallSourceExists}"` (in other words both criteria must be met in order for the button to be enabled). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options I can think of:-

1. Use a MultiBinding plus a custom `IMultiValueConverter` that checks both values are true.
2. Expose a new property on your "Item3" model that simply returns true if the other properties are both True. This is a cleaner approach, and means that if the logic changes in the future (e.g. you need to include a third bool property), you don't have to touch your XAML.

Comment: I typically use the second approach, for the same reasons you've specified.

Answer (score 0):

Use a multibinding like this:

```
<Button Name="ThirdPartyPostoneButton" Content="Postpone" Click ="postponeThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25" >
  <Button.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyCustomConvertor}">
      <Binding Path="Item3.CanDefer"/>
      <Binding Path="Item3.InstallSourceExists"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

Comment: Does this need an IMultiValueConverter? Or is WPF doing something clever because they are both boolean values, making a converter unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, you have to use IMultiValueConverter. I've updated my answer.